# jquery dialog while waiting for request

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i want to show a dialog while i am waiting for the request...the request opens a new site (same window) ... now my problem is it only opens me the dialog but it does not trigger the request!

I use Jquery ui 1.8.7.Here is my code snippet

Into the HTML Head:

```
<script>
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog_1" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 600
        });

        $( "#opener_1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog_1" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here my HTML Code

```
<div class="register_button"><button id="opener_1" type="submit">Send</button></div>
<!-- the submit button does trigger de request to!-->
<div id="dialog_1" title="register">
Please Wait!
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you making the request?

Comment: It seems that you exaggerated the waiting effect too much, and the request is not triggering:-)) Go and learn jQuery, or use ready-made templates from godaddy.

Comment: the request will be done with the button (type submit)... the goal is that the button makes the request while a dialog is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return false in on click will cancel the default operation.

if you want the dialog to be shown until the new page loads you will not get that result, unless you use ajax to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add the redirect to the jquery dialog initialization itself by adding it to the open event:

```
$( "#dialog_1" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 600,
                        open: function(event, ui) { 
                                 window.location.href = "nameofpage.html"; }
});
```

That way you keep the functionality together and ensure the redirect happens when the dialog pops up.